# from Facebook Graph API - can I get all friends' albums in 1 call?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So I can do one call to get all friends.
then iterate through and get albums for each friend.

the api/network overhead is insane as usually friend counts are super high.

is there anyway to get all the albums directly in that same original user.friends() call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) is your friend. Try this:

```
me/friends?fields=albums
```

If you've got a lot of friends, running this query could take some time.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thanks.. and this is still waaaaaaay faster than making an albums call for each friend =)